# Android Store Keywords

Tags: android, google-play, release

I've just started with programming Android apps and was wondering how to get my app to appear to people who search for generic words related to my app. For example, I wrote a simple tetris-like clone, but the word tetris is owned by a company if I'm not mistaken so I can't use that term in my descriptions. However if one does a search of the word "tetris" in the store, many apps will appear even though they don't mention the word "tetris" anywhere within is name, descriptions etc.

So I was wondering how exactly do people get keywords like this to direct to their app without explicitly mentioning it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

about from description, you can use tags too to make you app found. also the more rating you have the better your applications shows up. that is why some apps with huge rating shows up when some search query similar or has the same meaning with there keys words shows up.

Just work on you application's rating.